# Latest Chrome update blocks unsecure cookies in Angular

Tags: angular, google-chrome, cookies

We are using `ngx-cookie-service` to set session cookies for the logged in user. Everything was working fine, until yesterday as the latest release of Chrome have started to block unsecure cookies and showing the following message in console.

```
    A cookie associated with a resource at http://tradmin.novlence.com/ was set with `SameSite=None` 
    but without `Secure`. It has been blocked, as Chrome now only delivers cookies marked 
   `SameSite=None` if they are also marked `Secure`. You can review cookies in developer tools under 
    Application>Storage>Cookies and see more details at 
    https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5633521622188032.
```

We explored the documentation and found out the way to create secure cookies with the help of cookie options passed in the cookie service. But, now, the cookies are not being created at all. Following is the code snippet we tried to implement.

```
    let domain = "localhost";
    let path = '/';
    let secure = true;
    let expiry = new Date();
    expiry.setDate(expiry.getDate()+365);
    this.cookieService.set( 'token', user.accessToken,expiry,path,domain,secure,'None'); 
    this.cookieService.set( 'currentUser', JSON.stringify(user.admin),expiry,path,domain,secure,'None');
```

Can anybody show us the right direction as to where are we going wrong? It can be helpful to the entire community as lots of developers might be getting this issue as well. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of `ngx-cookie-service` are you using?

Comment: @KurtHamilton: We're using ^2.2.0 version of `ngx-cookie-service`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you're talking about can be easily found by looking at the github repos:

https://github.com/stevermeister/ngx-cookie-service/issues/76

This was an open issue until recently. You are currently using version 2.2, which was published 10 months ago. The fix was published 2 months ago.

You should be able to fix this problem by upgrading to 2.4. If this still doesn't fix the problem, you should raise a new issue.

Edit: You should check the version compatibility before upgrading. It looks like v2.3 supports Angular < 9, and v2.4+ supports Angular 9.

Comment: We were able to fix the issue using the version 3.0.2, and tweaking the usage of delete cookies method.